# How to make Smooth Scrolling work on a Next.js App

Tags: reactjs, smooth-scrolling, next.js

For parallax effect to work properly I needed smooth scrolling to work on a Next.js app. I’ve tried other libraries like ‘react-scroll’ which only works with links. But I needed smooth scrolling to work on the whole page for every page. In my additional effort to make smooth scrolling work on a Next.js app I’ve tried to add the following library like the following (since Next.js doesn’t support the ‘window’ object):

```
class Solutions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            this.ReallySmoothScroll = require('really-smooth-scroll');
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.ReallySmoothScroll.shim();
    } ...
...
...
```

But this ended up freezing the whole scrolling. Now no mouse based scrolling works, let alone smooth scrolling. I’m pretty new to this. Any help or suggestion to make smooth scrolling work on React/Nex.js apps will be highly appreciated. Also, any suggestion on React based parallax effects will be extremely helpful. Thanx in advance.